# Facing problem in making a login page user authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

My Username and Password are the same as saved in the database but still rather than redirecring me to access page it just keeps getting buffering in the login page without giving any error. So if you know the solution for it, please let me know

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    users.find({ email: username })
        .then(function (foundUser) {
            if (foundUser) {
                console.log("User Found");
                if (foundUser.password === password) {
                        res.render("access");
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
});
```

I have tried different type of logics but still facing the same issue

This is my client side ejs file

```
<div>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="username">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you *call* this code?  Eg is it on the click event of a button?  Sounds like the page's `<form>` is POSTing which reloads the page.   If this is the case, you need to cancel the submit, or change your button to `<button type='button' ..`.   If in a browser, open dev tools and watch the network tab

Comment: Show your clientside code.

Comment: If the password doesn’t match then you don’t make a response. If there is an exception then you don’t make a response. You need to handle those cases.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is an unsuitable hashing algorithm; you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: Oh, missed that earlier. If the user isn't found you don't send a response either.

Comment: And if you'd done the most basic debugging you'd have logged the username and password to make sure they were being read in the first place.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). The `for` attribute needs to match the `id` of the element is is labelling.

Comment: @Quentin I have used mongoose encryption i just haven't showed in this question

Comment: @Quentin Actually i am learning node js from GeekforGeeks and i have did the same as the site instructed me.

Comment: @ManthanChauhan — So you have some code which doesn't work and instead of showing us that code you're "simplified" it and shown us some different code?!

Comment: @Quentin No, the other code which includes a sign up page works completely i am just facing the problem in login page as it just keeps on buffering

Comment: See my earlier comments about adding logging to test your values and seeing which branches of your ifs and elses and catches you actually hit given that 3 out of 4 of them **don't try to send a response**.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your password comparison logic is correct.Store passwords in a hashed format in your database for better security. Storing passwords in plain text is risky.When comparing passwords, you should match the hashed version stored in the database with the hashed version of the password provided during login.

```
     const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
       
     //use async await and arrow function instead of using regular function for more concise and readable asynchronous operations.
        
       app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    try {
        const foundUser = await users.findOne({ email: username });

        if (foundUser) {
            console.log("User Found");
// use this logic if you want to compare with hashed password 
          //  const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password);

         //   if (match) {
            //    res.render("access"); // if passwords match-->allow access
           // } else {
                // Incorrect password
                // Handle incorrect password scenario
           // }
           //if password is in plain text then use this :
            if (foundUser.password === password) {
                    res.render("access");
                } else {
                    // Password mismatch
                    // Handle incorrect password scenario
                }
        } else {
            // User not found with the provided email
            // Handle scenario when user does not exist
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // Handle other errors
    }
});
```